# Need an Apache Redirect Rule

Tags: apache

I need to redirect urls in such a way as shown below.

> http://**server1**/em/10_10_26_01_02?utm_content=Top-Join-Now-Link&utm_medium=Web-version&utm_campaign=Email-send2&utm_source=InfoUSA&CMPID=778374938793

to

> http://**server2**/em/10_10_26_01_02?utm_content=Top-Join-Now-Link&utm_medium=Web-version&utm_campaign=Email-send2&utm_source=InfoUSA&CMPID=778374938793

I need to change the url from Server1 to Server2 other than that every thing is same. One more thing is like the remaining string wont be static and it will changes each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

you need the following rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^server1
RewriteRule (.*) http://server2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

See here for more details : http://scriptplayground.com/tutorials/apache/Redirect-to-new-domain/